# A site to upload my code projects to

Tags: web-apps, web-development, source-code

Is there a web app that I can upload my own coding projects to, for the primary purpose of allowing those with a direct link to them to view source code and download the files? I want to accomplish this without setting up a hosting solution, relying purely on a web service.

The web app **needs** to:

- Allow me to upload code projects in the form of individual files or folders
- Make the source code of uploaded projects visible to visitors
- Allow the files themselves to be downloaded

**Optionally**, I'd also like the web app to:

- Turn the source code of code projects into working demos that I can then link people to (*ala CodePen*)
- Make the source code visible on a per-project basis as opposed to an  all-or-nothing one

Comment: [github pages](https://pages.github.com) would be good if your project is a static website. What is the application built with?

Comment: Does GitHub allow one to host non-FOSS projects? Mayeb the OP does nto want to share his source code

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185) That in mind: You're asking for a web app to self-host, I assume? Can you give a few more details (server specifics, required features, pricing expectations)?

Comment: I'm not asking for self-hosting, I'm asking whether there is a web app (i.e. a website) that will allow me to create an account and host my own code files on there, for others to be able to view the source of and download for their own use. max was on topic with GitHub pages, I'm looking for any services similar to this. It's on topic as per http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/45/20008 and http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3944/113316.

Comment: Also: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/219/20008.

Comment: Why am I being down-voted for this? The question is on-topic, as demonstrated above.

Comment: @Hashim Re-read the comments. Asking for a web site is *not* in scope for this site.

Comment: It's not a website, i.e. a static website designed to hold information, it's a web app - a website with specific purposes that functions as online software - and as per the last three links I posted above, web apps are on topic. To quote one: `This is a software recommendation site. Whether the software runs on your phone, on your laptop, on your home server, on your rented cloud instance, on your company server or on someone else's servers doesn't change the on-topicness of the question.`

Comment: @Hashim: The very next paragraph of the quoted answer is: "Hosting, however, is off-topic."

Comment: There's nothing ostensibly related to "hosting" about the site I'm looking for. When I use the term "host" in my question it's pretty clear that I'm using it in the generic sense of the word, and that could just as eaisly be replaced with upload/store. I'm not looking for web hosting, I'm looking for a web app where I can "host" i.e. upload, some files. See the answers here http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/683/20008 and here http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/742/20008 which draw a clear distinction between the two.

Comment: To make it clearer, I'll remove any references to "host" in my question, but I honestly thought it was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I'm running a [Ubuntu server](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) with [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) as web server and [SVN](https://subversion.apache.org/) for the source code repository. That works stable since several years.

It's free (open source), provides full source code version control and you can use Apache to serve "normal" files as well.

There will be several hosters all around the world renting a root server to you, giving you access to your files from anywhere. But you could also run it at your homw and e.g. use [DynDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) to access the server.

Comment: At the moment, paying for hosting nor hosting my own server at home are too costly for me, so those options are out for the time being.